# Formulas for the definition of set pre/image

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I refer to Wiki page below as I write down my question.

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a function with $A \subseteq X, B \subseteq Y$. On Wiki the definition of inverse image is given as $f^{-1}[B] = \{x \in X: f(x) \in B\}$ which in my book is also rendered as $x \in f^{-1}(B) \iff f(x) \in B.$

Wiki also gives the definition of image set as $f[A] = \{f(x): x \in A\}$. For this case my book doesn't have a pretty formula like the one above. The examples section of the Wiki page has $f(\{−2, 3\}) = \{4, 9\}$ where $f(x) = x^2$. But $f(2), f(-3) \in \{4, 9\}$, yet $2, -3 \not \in \{-2, 3\}$. Maybe that's why there's no pretty formula for this case.

Given what I wrote above, I'll try to justify why the formulas above (don't) work.

Statement: $x \in f^{-1}(B) \iff f(x) \in B.$

Proof: Let $x \in f^{-1}[B].$ Then by definition of $f^{-1}[B]$, we have $x \in X$ s.t. $f(x) \in B$. Now suppose $f(x) \in B.$ Since $f$ is a function, $f(x)$ must have a pre-image $x$ in the domain of $f$ which is $X$. But by definition of $f^{-1}[B]$ such an element $x$ must be in $f^{-1}[B]$.

Statement: it's not true that $x \in A \iff f(x) \in f(A)$.

Proof: The Wiki page already gave a counterexample, but I'd like to render it as a direct proof to hone my proof-writing skills. Suppose $x \in A$. Since $f$ is a function, $f(x)$ must be in the image of $f$ (distinct from the image of $A$) which is $f(X).$ The image of $A$ is $f(A)$ where $f(A) \subseteq f(X).$ But $f(x) \not \in f(X) \setminus f(A)$ as by definition of $f(A)$ we have that any $f(x) \in f(X) \subseteq Y$ with $x \in A$ must be in $f(A)$. Now let $f(x) \in f(A).$ Since $f$ is a function, $f(x)$ must have a pre-image $x$ in the domain of $f$ which is $X$. But $A \subseteq X$ and nothing precludes $x$ for being in $X \setminus A.$ That means we cannot claim $f(x) \in f(A) \implies x \in A.$

I have two questions:

(1) Do the proofs above work?

(2) Can I alter the definition of image set given on Wiki page to $f[A] = \{f(x) \in Y: x \in A\}$ to make it look a bit more symmetrical with  $f^{-1}[B] = \{x \in X: f(x) \in B\}$?

[Wiki page on image set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof essentially comes down to the phrase "nothing precludes $x$ for being in $X∖A$." The only way to justify a statement such as this is to give a counterexample. Generally in math, if you wish to show that a statement is true, the way to do it is with a proof. If you wish to show that a statement is false, you must construct a counterexample. (Note that one direction of your statement is true, namely that $x\in A\implies f(x)\in f(A)$. The fact that the converse is false requires counterexample.)

For the second part of your question, you could define $f^{-1}(A)=\{y\in Y:\exists x\in A \mbox{ s.t. } f(x)=y\}$. I don't know if this is more to your liking or not.

Comment: Thanks. As you don't seem to object to the rest of my OP, your post answers my questions in their entirety.

Comment: Happy to help! Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.